# Python Error : "Error binding parameter - probably unsupported type"

Tags: python, sql, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a column 'a' in a dataframe where the data looks this:

> [[-1.13855, -1.13855, -1.2212, -1.27331, -1.32733, -1.39211, -1.46947, -1.55818, -1.65584, -1.75972, -1.86731, -1.97665, -2.08624, -2.19495, -2.30196, -2.40665, -2.50857, -2.60744, -2.70314, -2.79567, -2.885, -2.97102, -3.05448, -3.13868, -3.22736, -3.31942, -3.41041, -3.49954, -3.59207, -3.69467, -3.81331, -3.96048, -4.15626, -4.43863, -4.90479, -5.79363, -6.24746, -4.26896, -3.14354, -2.44187, -1.9507, -1.57115, -1.23503, -0.893369, -0.528228, -0.0869591, 0.616627, 0.406154, -0.479933, -0.479933],...]]

I have been told its a numpy array (not sure if that's the case, correct me if I'm wrong...)

I wish to put this dataframe into an sql database using pandas to_sql method.

In order to do so, I need to convert this 'object' to a dtype that sql accepts e.g. string.

I must be able to write it as a string and then retrieve it as a numpy array (or whatever it is).

However, I am having an error as mentioned in the title.

my code currently sort of looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
import sqlalchemy
import numpy as np
import io

from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.strptime('2020-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

testdata = {'time': time , 'a': [[[-1.13855, -1.13855, -1.2212, -1.27331, -1.32733, -1.39211, -1.46947, -1.55818, -1.65584, -1.75972, -1.86731, -1.97665, -2.08624, -2.19495, -2.30196, -2.40665, -2.50857, -2.60744, -2.70314, -2.79567, -2.885, -2.97102, -3.05448, -3.13868, -3.22736, -3.31942, -3.41041, -3.49954, -3.59207, -3.69467, -3.81331, -3.96048, -4.15626, -4.43863, -4.90479, -5.79363, -6.24746, -4.26896, -3.14354, -2.44187, -1.9507, -1.57115, -1.23503, -0.893369, -0.528228, -0.0869591, 0.616627, 0.406154, -0.479933, -0.479933]]]}  
testdata = pd.DataFrame(testdata,index=['time'])
testdata
test_rows=[]
for index,row in testdata.iterrows():
  t=row['time']
  a=row['a'].astype('str')
  new_rows = {'time': t , 'a':a}
  test_rows.append(pd.Series(new_rows))

testframe = pd.DataFrame(test_rows)
testframe.set_index('time')
print(testframe.dtypes)
testframe

testframe.to_sql(name='Data2_mcw_conv',con=conn,if_exists='replace',index=True)
```

output:

```
time    datetime64[ns]
a               object
dtype: object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-c434bf1560a6> in <module>()
     27 testframe
     28 
---> 29 testframe.to_sql(name='testframe',con=conn,if_exists='replace',index=True)
     30 
     31 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
   1553     def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
   1554         data_list = list(data_iter)
-> 1555         conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(num_rows=1), data_list)
   1556 
   1557     def _execute_insert_multi(self, conn, keys, data_iter):

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Before attempting to convert to sql using to_sql, the index seems to be an integer instead of time even if I explicitly set the time to be the index with set_index.

From here, I have the following problems:

1. How do I rectify this error?
2. For some reason, my index is an integer, how do I make the time column the index?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your column `a` is already in string `dtype`. In pandas dataframes if a column have string values it will display its `dtype` as `object`. Check this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan I see, thank you for the insight. However, why do I then get this error when I try to do a to_sql with it?